# Calling custom plugin from view helper

Tags: php, zend-framework3, zend-controller-plugin

Is there any way to call custom plugin from view helper in ZF3?

As per ZF3, the Factory for the Helper is created by me.

In ZF2 this is how we call the Plugin.

```
$ecommercePlugin = $this->getServiceLocator()
->get('ControllerPluginManager')
->get('CustomPlugin');
```

As serviceLocator is removed from ZF3, how to call the plugin?

**Edit**
`module.config`

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'CustomPlugin' => \MyMethod\Controller\Plugin\CustomPlugin::class
    )
),
```

`MymethodController\CustomPlugin`

```
class CustomPlugin extends AbstractPlugin
{
     //My methods
}
```

Comment: Did you fix your problem? Or still need help?

Comment: @SzymonM Need help. Please.

Comment: Do you get any error? What's happen when you do `$this->customPlugin()` in view?

Comment: @SzymonM customPlugin not found in <path_to_the_helper>/CustomHelper.php

Comment: Show this `path_to_the_helper` and your view where you call this plugin

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend registering the `CustomPlugin` with the `ViewHelperManager`. You can find information about configuration in [Zend's Manual](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html). This is typically how your Module's `module.config.php` may look:

```
<?php
    return [
        'controller_plugins' => [
            'invokables' => [
                'CustomPlugin' => \MyMethod\Controller\Plugin\CustomPlugin::class
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

To register it for use as a view helper you would add:

```
<?php
    return [
        'controller_plugins' => [
            'invokables' => [
                'CustomPlugin' => \MyMethod\Controller\Plugin\CustomPlugin::class
            ],
        ],
        'view_helpers' => [
            'invokables' => [
                'CustomPlugin' => \MyMethod\Controller\Plugin\CustomPlugin::class 
            ]
        ],
    ];
```

This new config will allow you to call `$this->CustomPlugin()` from both controllers and views. Now, you may run into a situation in which you need to inject dependencies into your plugin/view helper. In this case you can simply create a factory class to handle finding and injecting the dependencies and change your config to:

```
<?php
    return [
        'controller_plugins' => [
            'factories' => [
                'CustomPlugin' => \MyMethod\Controller\Plugin\CustomPlugin::class
            ],
        ],
        'view_helpers' => [
            'factories' => [
                'CustomPlugin' => \MyMethod\Controller\Plugin\CustomPlugin::class 
            ]
        ],
    ];
```

Now when the plugin/view helper is called, the factory will run and assemble the desired class. Let me know if you have any questions. There is a lot of flexibility in the config and with specific requirements or an example of the `CustomPlugin` class and your `Module.php`/`module.config.php` config could provide a more accurate example of what you are looking for.

Comment: I have configured plugin as your suggestion. But didn't worked for me. Error >Call to Undefined Method <path_to_helper>::CustomPlugin()

Comment: Can you post your plugin class and config?

Comment: Is there a constructor in the plugin with any dependencies being injected? Or, are there any being loaded with an initializer that you know of?

Comment: No sir. There is not any dependencies.

Comment: I would double-check the namespacing of your class. I noticed your update has the namespace as `MymethodController\CustomPlugin` but the module config has `\MyMethod\Controller\Plugin\CustomPlugin::class`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139257/discussion-between-curtis-kelsey-and-keyur-k).